# Parse Temperature Value:

Tags: grep

```
dinesh@ubuntu:~/myapps/batMon$ acpi -t
Thermal 0: ok, 50.5 degrees C
```

From the above output, I would like to parse only the temperature value using grep command.How to grep? Appreciate all your suggestions

Comment: `acpi -t | grep -o '..[.].'` or `acpi -t | grep -o [0-9][0-9].[0-9]` where `-o` means `--only-matching` and another part is the string expression.

Comment: As long as it's always gonna keep such format: `grep -o [[:digit:]][[:digit:]].[[:digit:]]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as it's always gonna keep such format:

```
acpi -t | grep -o [[:digit:]][[:digit:]].[[:digit:]]
```

Will only print out the string that **matches the pattern**, i.e. two consecutive digits followd by a dot and another digit.